# How to pass the search query to table filter between different JS files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a datagrid table in which I'm getting my database data from an API call and I have written the table code in one file. I also have a search functionality where you can search for a particular record inside the table, but this search code is in another file. I am having difficulty of passing my state variable containing the search parameter from my search file to the table file. I have separated all my components in different pages since it'd be easier to structure them using a grid in my App.js. How do I get my search query to my table file next?

My search code:

```
export default function SearchInput() {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <Grid item xs={3}>
        <Box mt={1.6}
            component="form"
            sx={{
                '& > :not(style)': { m: 1, width: '20ch', backgroundColor: "white", borderRadius: 1},
            }}
            noValidate
            autoComplete="off"
        >
        <TextField 
          placeholder="Search Customer ID" 
          variant="outlined" 
          size="small" 
          sx={{input: {textAlign: "left"}}} 
          onChange={(event) => {
            setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
            console.log(searchTerm);
          }}
        />
        </Box>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

My table code:

```
export default function DataTable() {
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = React.useState(10);
  
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  useEffect(async () => {
    setData(await getData());
  }, [])


    return (
      <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <DataGrid
            rows={data}
            columns={columns}
            checkboxSelection={true}
            autoHeight={true}
            density='compact'
            rowHeight='40'
            headerHeight={80}
            disableColumnMenu={true}
            disableSelectionOnClick={true}
            sx={datagridSx}

            pageSize={pageSize}
            onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
            rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 15]}
            pagination
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container maxWidth="false" disableGutters="true">
        <Grid container spacing={0}>
          <ABClogo />
          <HHHlogo />
        </Grid>
        <Grid container spacing={0}>
          <LeftButtonGroup />
          <SearchInput />
          <RightButtonGroup />
        </Grid>
        <Grid container spacing={0}>
          <DataTable />
          <TableFooter />
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Looking at `App.js`, it appears that `<SearchInput />` and `<DataTable />` are siblings. So, if one needs to send data between these two React components, one will need to `move the state up`. In other words, the `search parameter` needs to be declared at a component which is parent to both the js files. There are several alternatives to this. One that comes to mind is to use `state management` such as `Redux`.

Comment: Okay so I need to declare `searchTerm` as a parent to both the js files. Do you have any sample code I can refer to

Comment: [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) is one of the items explained in [ReactJS docs](https://reactjs.org/docs). It is my understanding that the current issue you report may be resolved by employing this knowledge to your circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example using `createContext()`, and `useReducer()` to lift up state and share it between components, similar to what you are after, but as [jsNoob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13658816/jsn00b) says, there are multiple options. This is one I'm comfortable with.

The concept is explained here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Essentially you can create 'global' state at any point in your component tree and using Provider / Consumer components, share that state and functionality with child components.

```
//Main.js

import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

const MainContext = createContext();

export const useMainContext => {
    return useContext(MainContext);
}

const mainReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case: 'SOMETHING':{
            return({...state, something: action.data});
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const Main = () => {
    const [mainState, mainDispatch] = useReducer(mainReducer, {something: false});
    const stateOfMain = { mainState, mainDispatch };
    
    return(
        <MainContext.Provider value={stateOfMain}>
            <MainContext.Consumer>
                {() => (
                    <div>
                        <Nothing />
                        <Whatever />
                    </div>
                )}
            </MainContext.Consumer>
        </MainContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Then you can have the other components use either or both of the main state and dispatch.

```
//Nothing.js
import {mainContext} from './Main.js'

const Nothing = () => {
    const { mainState, mainDispatch } = useMainContext();
    
    return(
        <button onClick={() => {mainDispatch({type: 'SOMETHING', data: !mainState.something})}}></button>
    )
}
```

Clicking the button in the above file, should change the display of the below file

```
//Whatever.js
import {mainContext} from './Main.js'

const Whatever = () => {
    const { mainState } = useMainContext();
    
    return(
        <div>{mainState.something}</div>
    );
}
```